# Bash "for file in" exception

Tags: bash, shell

I got this

```
for file in *; do
    any command
done
```

What I want to do is add an exception to the "for file in *; do".

Any ideas?

Comment: By "exception", do you mean you want to exclude one or more files from being matched by `*`? If so, you can use an `if` statement inside the loop to avoid acting on particular files.

Comment: What do you mean by an exception? `if [[ $file != exception ]] ; then ... ; fi`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wanted to skip files with a particular extension, for example, ".pl", you could do:

```
for file in *
do
    [ "${file##*.}" != "pl" ] && echo $file
done
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, an extension checker. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do what I think you are asking is to loop through and check a file name with a if statement (or just grep -v the ls cmd):

```
for file in `ls`; do
    if [ "$file" == "something" ]; then
        # do something
    else
        # something else
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, you have files

```
$ ls -1 ./
./M2U0001.MPG
./M2U0180.MPG
./text
```

Exception file is M2U0180.MPG

```
$> filename="M2U0180.MPG"
```

And

```
$> for file in $(ls -1 ./* | grep --invert-match "${filename}" ); do echo $file; done
./M2U0001.MPG
./text
```

Weird solution done :)

Comment: Very nice improv over here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

use bash's extended globbing

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in !(excluded-file); do echo "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution :
The following code snippet will print all the files in the pwd , that have a .py extension

```
for i in * ;do
        if  [[ $i == *.py ]];then
                    echo "$i"
        fi
done
```